# MYSQL Variable using SET results in Discrepancies in behavior

Tags: mysql, variables, set, session-variables

Why is is that when using SET to set variables, in some cases multiple variables can be set with one statement and in others two separate ones need to be issued.

For example this works fine:

```
SET
@uname := 'John',
@acct_trade := 218.01,
@acct_labor := 518.01,
@acct_cntgy := 818.01;
```

Only one semicolon is used.

However when its something like this:

```
SET @datestart := '2012-01-01',
SET @dateend :=  '2012-02-29';
```

It doesn't work. I have to make them each its own call.

```
SET @datestart := '2012-01-01';
SET @dateend :=  '2012-02-29';
```

I am assuming that this has something to do with the fact that its asking for 2 strings. I even tried casting it to date.

Any ideas?

Comment: if newfurniturey's answer has solved your problem, you could accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example that fails, you have the `SET` keyword twice. If you remove it from the second line it should work:

```
SET
@datestart := '2012-01-01',
@dateend :=  '2012-02-29';
```

This is because the `SET` keyword acts as a full statement up-until the ending semi-colon. When it hits another `SET` keyword, it's invalid syntax.

Comment: LOL. wow thanks. I cant believe that I missed that... I sat here for almost 2 hours trying to figure out why it wasn't working...

Second pair of eyes... Much appreciated.